# How to add .app.src file in an independent module/handler (.erl file)

Tags: erlang, entity-relationship, erlang-shell, erlang-supervisor, game-maker-language

I am working on an erlang application. I want to compile and run one .erl file from src/ folder which is using environment variables from .app.src file.

So my requirement is to add .app.src file in a handler and compile/run .erl file independently. How to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [application:load/1](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#load-1) to load the .app file without starting it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is addition to previous answer (Jose M). Imagine the handler module (handler.erl) looks like:

```
-module(handler).
-export([start/0]).
start() ->
  R1 = application:load(dynconf),
  io:format(user, "After app load.   R2=~p~n", [R1]),
  Test = application:get_env(dynconf, test),
  io:format(user, "After config changed. Test=~p~n~n", [Test]).
```

and file dynconf.app (it defines idle application to use only for env tuple definition):

```
{application,dynconf,
             [{description,"dynamically (on fly) change configuration"},
              {vsn,"0.0.1"},
              {registered,[]},
              {applications,[]},
              {modules,[]},
              {mod,{dynconf,[]}},
              {env,[{test,7}]}]}.
```

Then run Erlang shell in folder with two above files:

```
1> c("handler.erl").
{ok,handler}
2> handler:start().
After app load.   R2=ok
After config changed. Test={ok,7}
```

You have got an environment var `test` = 7 from dynconf.app file. dynconf.app.src is used by rebar to generate dynconf.app and copy it to ebin folder. But for alone *.erl file (without rebar project) you can create *.app file yourself by hand.